# Combining spreadsheets in python using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

So, I have a little bit of code that I'm trying to work together to combine spreadsheets in python. Here is the (updated/edited) code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from os.path import basename

df = []

#enter your file names via terminal

file1 = raw_input("Enter the path to the first file(don't forget to include the extension (.xlsx for Windows)):")

file2 = raw_input("Enter the path to the second file(don't forget to include the extension (.xlsx for Windows)):")


#combine the .xlsx files

for f in [file1, file2]:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1').iloc[:-2]
    data.index = [os.path.basename(f)] * len(data)
    df.append(data)

#add the column that includes the original file

data.index = [basename(f)] * len(data)

#set the path and name of your final product file

final = raw_input('Where do you want the file, and what do you want to name it? Format you answer as such: (C:\path_to_file\name_of_file.xlsx):')

df = pd.concat(df)

df.to_excel(final)
```

The test inputs are:

```
Product   Inventory Price   Sold
Banana    50        $1.00    27
Grapes    100       $3.00    68
```

and

```
Product        Inventory    Price   Sold
Oranges        68           $3.00   17
Apples         22           $1.50   9
Strawberries   245          $4.00   122
```

And yet, the result I get is:

```
                Product Inventory   Price   Sold
dbtest2.xlsx    Oranges 68             3    17
```

Ideally, the final product will look like this:

```
                Product       Inventory Price   Sold
dbtest2.xlsx    Oranges           68    $3       17
dbtest2.xlsx    Apples            22    $1.50    9
dbtest2.xlsx    Strawberries      245   $4.00    122
dbtest1.xlsx    Banana            50    $1.00    27
dbtest1.xlsx    Grapes            100   $3.00    68
```

It's only taking one item from the second list... Why is this?

Comment: The test inputs you show, converted to dataframes, have no problem with concat.  Have you confirmed that your inputs are actually producing exactly the dataframes you expect?

Comment: They aren't, that's the issue.

Comment: Do you mean this solves the problem, i.e. that the problem was dbtest2.xlsx and/or  dbtest1.xlsx were producing dataframes that didn't match your expectations?

Comment: The frames should be combined. I'll update the question in a moment to show what it would ideally look like.

Comment: I understand that you want to combine the inputs.  I'm asking what your inputs actually look like. You are producing dataframes from dbtest2.xlsx and/or dbtest1.xlsx.  When you check those dataframes, do they look identical to the "test inputs" you show in your question?  Because the script you show will properly join those "test inputs", meaning the simplest explanation is that your actual inputs are not the same as those ones.

Comment: The inputs are listed in the question.

Comment: The inputs are not listed in the question.  Your code shows inputs being imported from Excel.  You do not show the Excel sheets; instead you show the dataframes that you think have been made from those sheets. However, your code works fine with the inputs you show.  Therefore I am asking you either to show code actually using the inputs you show, or to test whether the excel inputs actually do generate those inputs.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the confusion. Beneath the question I state the test inputs. Those ARE the excel files I'm using, I just blocked it off as code to separate it from the rest of it, perhaps my mistake. So those inputs are in fact the excel files dbtest1 and dbtest2.

Comment: No, those dataframes are NOT the excel files.  Excel files are excel files, dataframes are pandas concepts.  What I'm asking you is if you are certain that the Excel files actually do turn into those pandas dataframes.  Read each file to a dataframe and then immediately print it out to confirm.  More generally, I'm asking you to debug your program by investigating all the intermediate steps, to find where the problem is.

Comment: I figured out what it was. ".iloc[:-2]" was, well, doing what it's supposed to do, in that it was getting rid of the last two submissions in each excel sheet. Figured this out awhile ago, just forgot to revisit page.